# Credit Card Contributions entered by staff listed as complete but never made it to authorizenet

Tags: civicontribute, authorize.net

recently taken over support for a very complex drupal 7/Civi 4.7.x site (which I'm happy to say was very well built by the initial team).

One of the issues that we've found reviewing things is that there are a number of contributions that were entered by the staff of the organization that are listed in civi as complete but do not show up anywhere in authorizenet. Other contributions entered by donors themselves were processed and paid but these have fallen into a void -- and these are some large donations.

As you can imagine this is causing a lot of stress. People thought they donated and never got billed; the org thinks it has money that was never processed so actually does not exist.

Has anyone seen anything like this in the past? I can't go back in time and fix the broken donations but what can I do to try to make sure this does not continue to happen?

Comment: i think we had something similar and it was due to having a CiviRules triggered by a new contribution or something like that. if you have civirules in place pls add that info and i may have some more ideas to offer

Comment: thanks for that comment, for some reason I was not thinking about the possibility of this being extension related but now that I look, there is a custom extension that modifies the back end donations forms

I'll post more details when I fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a lot of exploration it seems that this turns out to be user error caused by confusion about how CiviCRM multisite works.

The organization has multiple sub-groups, each having its own credit card processor account. The main www site was assumed by staff to be a master that had access to everything, but for the credit card processors it is just another subsite. So staff entering data logged into the main subsite were entering donations for other subsites. Those donations did not vanish, they just went into the wrong bank account.